# Button onclick event in Javascript does not trigger alerts

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, alert

I'm trying to make a simple register/login system but when I press the button for both, it doesn't do what I need it to do.

I put

```
alert("I work!");
```

at the beginning of each function supposed to work to see if it actually gets triggered but it doesn't. I also checked if the onclick events for both are referenced correctly and they are. I even tried to copy the actual scripts into the html file to ensure that it's not a reference issue. At this point, I'm really stuck, and if this is some syntax error, it doesn't alert me and I'm not aware of any.

The codes are:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Opportunities</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Uwu</p>

        <form>
            <p>Username <input type="text" class="username" /></p>
            <p>Password <input type="password" class="password" /></p>
            <button onclick="loginUser()">Login</button>
        </form>

        <p>Not yet registered? <a href="/register">Click here to create an account.</a> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

registration.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src=/js/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Registration page</p>

        <form>
            <p>Username <input type="text" class="username" /></p>
            <p>Password <input type="password" class="password" /></p>
            <button onclick="registerUser()">Register</button>
            <!--onclick event doesn't work-->
        </form>

        <p><a href="/">Click here to go back.</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

and script.js:

```
var url = "http://localhost:8888";

function test(){
    console.log('hello');
}

function registerUser(){
    alert("I work!");
    var username = document.getElementbyClassName("username");
    var password = document.getElementbyClassName("password");

    $.ajax{(
        url: url + "/register",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            username: username[0].value,
            password: password[0].value
        }
        success: function(respons){
            alert(response.message);
        }
    }).error(function(response){
        alert(response.message);
    });
}

function loginUser(){
    alert("I work!");
    var username = document.getElementbyClassName("username");
    var password = document.getElementbyClassName("password");

    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/login",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            username: username[0].value,
            password: password[0].value
        }
    }).success(function(response){
        alert(response.message);
    }).error(function(response){
        alert(response.message);
    });
}
```

Whenever I press the buttons for each, it just clears the texts in my inputs but doesn't launch an alert like I intend to. Please do tell me what I should check regarding this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is not loaded

Remove the frist backslash  ('/') from

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src=/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: loginUser() and registerUser() in the button parameters are defined as what I want them to be defined. I tried removing the slash as well and it doesn't work still.

Comment: check your browser  console ? what is error reported

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your browser I would try first that you dont have any "popup" script blocking extensions, I had the same issue and the issue was chrome popup js blocker cause simple adblocker doesnt work for some sites.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in the `registerUser()` function try changing the ajax call to

```
$.ajax({
    url: url + "/register",
    method: "post",
    data: {
        username: username[0].value,
        password: password[0].value
    },
    success: function(respons){
        alert(response.message);
    }
}).error(function(response){
    alert(response.message);
});
```